# libreoffice calc failing to autosave despite configured to, losing hours of progress

Tags: libreoffice

UPDATE: I've finally beared witness to it failing to observe the auto-save settings (even though it did earlier, and I've changed nothing in the config file).  I type something into a cell and hit enter, wait 3 minutes (it's set to save every 2 minutes) and neither the main file or the backup get updated.

This problem is happening with libreoffice calc 4 in both windows 7 and my debian box.

Ok the weird thing here is that I cannot willingly reproduce this bug (I have to assume that is what it is).  I.e. I have libreoffice set to save every five minutes to backup and the main file, and every time I commit a change to my calc spreadsheet and then leave it alone, I see the timestamps update on the files in both the main and backup directories within five minutes.  I.e. when I hold a microscope to the problem, suddenly everything seems as it should be!

But for some mysterious reason, if I close libreoffice in a way that it considers unclean (which seems to be anything that isn't manually closing--you cannot logout, shut the computer down and expect it to save the current session) and the recovery dialog box appears when I try to reopen my spreadsheet later, I can usually expect hours of progress to be doomed.

Whether I try to cancel the recovery process or go through with what it asks (the latter which often, but not always, produces file permission errors) I get set back to a much earlier version of the spreadsheet.  It happened just last night--I made changes on it well into early morning, and after going to bed had my pc on the entire time with the spreadsheet open so there was plenty of time to save, I accidentally logged out the session though the following morning--when I logged back in this afternoon the progress was last saved 9pm the previous day!?

I really am left scratching my head at this, not to mention very distressed at so much work repeatedly going down the drain.  And even more oddly it seems to be a low profile problem or one only I am having, as I see nobody else discussing it when I search for it.

Anyone got any ideas?